# Как вызвать процедуру в цикле?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Создал процедуру в SQL Developer. Вот её упрощённый код:

```
create or replace procedure add_parameters (tablename varchar2) as 
begin
    null;
    /** Далее логика процедуры
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE '||tablename||' ADD(FB_AREA_HA Float)';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE '||tablename||' SET FB_AREA_HA = FB_AREA/10000';
    */
end add_parameters;
/
```

Могу её вызвать и она работает, как и ожидалось:

```
execute add_parameters ('BBX_PARAMS');
```

> PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Однако если я попытаюсь использовать ее в цикле над набором таблиц, то получу ошибку:

```
set serverout on
declare
    sql_stmnt varchar2 (400);
begin
    for x in (select * from all_tables where table_name like 'BBX_%')
    loop
        sql_stmnt := 'execute add_parameters ('''||x.table_name||''')';
        dbms_output.put_line (sql_stmnt||';');
        execute immediate sql_stmnt;
    end loop;
end;
/
```

> Error report -
> ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
> ORA-06512: at line 8

Что вызывает эту ошибку? Хотя я почти уверен, что это не в 8-й строчке.

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Calling Oracle procedure in for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54786815) от участника [@blabbath](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7699040/blabbath)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/54786815

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка как раз в 8-й строке:

```
execute immediate sql_stmnt;
```

[EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/dynamic-sql.html#GUID-30ADFC05-8DFB-4C8A-831D-426C2E97F217) это PL/SQL комманда, которая выполняет динамический запрос в SQL контексте. Но [EXECUTE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/EXECUTE.html#GUID-A64F29C8-B5C7-426D-82E9-A8E85763F3D6) не является командой SQL. Это команда клиентских инструментов, таких как SQL*Plus, SQL Developer и пр., и является ничем иным, как короткой записью для анонимного блока:

```
begin
    add_parameters ('params');
end;
/
```

Так как, цикл уже находится в PL/SQL блоке, то динамический SQL для вызова процедуры не нужен, и даже, неуместен. Для вызова процедуры, надо просто указать её в блоке, вот так:

```
begin
    for x in (select * from all_tables where table_name like 'BBX_%')
    loop
        add_parameters (x.table_name);
    end loop;
end;
```